# What are the assumptions for the Bayesian average?

Tags: bayesian

How does one derive the Bayesian average (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average). As I understand it, this should derivable from the prior probability distribution for $\bar{x}$ and the likelihood function of a sample given a particular $\bar{x}$. However, I'm not able to figure out what prior and likelihood lead to formula in the link.

Comment: Under some forms of Bayesian model and prior for the population mean, this would correspond to a posterior mean, but it doesn't look to be formally Bayesian. It seems to be related to the less formal forms of [credibility theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credibility_theory#Actuarial_credibility), which have been around for a very long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked definition of "Bayesian Average" appears to be essentially heuristic,  and it is not entirely clear what you are asking.

However one possible interpretation is in the context of [MAP estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation) of the mean parameter $\mu$ for a Gaussian population. In this context the sample mean
$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_ix_i$$
is a [MLE for $\mu$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters).

To get the linked formula from a MAP framework, you could use a Gaussian prior for $\mu$ such that the MAP estimate becomes
$$\mu_\text{MAP}|\vec{x}=\frac{N\bar{x}+N_0\mu_0}{N+N_0}$$

The required prior is then
$$\mu\sim\text{N}(\mu_0,\sigma^2/N_0)$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the variance used in the likelihood, i.e. $x\sim\text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

So it is like specifying the "prior sample size" $N_0$ in terms of a ["standard error"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean).

(Note however that the formula is really heuristic, but that is OK, and it is reasonable without needing this sort of circuitous and assumption-laden justification!)

Answer (score 0):

Your prior belief is that the average of a typical dataset with $C$ samples is equal to $m$. Your real dataset has $n$ samples $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Therefore, combining your prior belief with this dataset you would have $C+n$ samples with a sum equal to $Cm+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$. Therefore, the average of your dataset considering the prior belief would be equal to
$$\bar x=\frac{Cm+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{C+n}$$